# Differentiate tablet with phone in manifest

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, android-manifest

Is it possible to differentiate tablet with a phone in manifest: I would like to say if tablet open tablet.class Java file or else open phone.class as the main screen.

I know I can do a setcontentview according to the tablet or phone but the problem is that the layout names and other things are different in both phone and tablet.

For example:

**TabletActivity.xml**

Layout 1 and Layout 2 with two buttons.

But for **PhoneActivity.xml**

Layout 1, Layout 2, Layout 3, Layout 4 with 4 buttons.

So If I use same JAVA file - I will end up having long code with conditions - instead if I could differentiate this in the beginning like If tablet just open tablet.class if not open phone.class - It would be easier for me?

**AGAIN:** I am able to differentiate tablet with phone in my mainactivity.java file. I try ing to know will I be able to do it in manifest reason because I have 20 different theme so I have 20 different xml file for tablet and phone and one java file (right now, Oncreate of my mainactivity - before setcontent I am checking if phone or tablet and then theme value and setting the content accordingly). I am wondering is there any easier way than this method???

Or shall I use two different APK's that works only for phone or tablet?

Is this possible?

Let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I know this.. This relates to xml files.. I wanted it for Java files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. You can get the screen inches

```
String inputSystem;
inputSystem = android.os.Build.ID;
Log.d("hai",inputSystem);
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated
Log.d("hai",width+"");
Log.d("hai",height+"");
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
double x = Math.pow(width/dm.xdpi,2);
double y = Math.pow(height/dm.ydpi,2);
double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x+y);
Log.d("hai","Screen inches : " + screenInches+"");
```

after that you just decide what is tablet and what is phone by screenInches

Answer (score 0):

Screen inches alone won't do it.  Lots of devices are in the "muddy" middle ground and could be called "phablet".

We use layouts to set our device. We use res/layout-sw600dp and res/layout-sw720dp folders. they correspond to devices of the smallest width of 600 or 720 display pixels which makes a nice determinant for 7" or 10" tablet sizes

You will be better served by following the Android guidelines for determining the device size with this link

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html

Comment: Not a solution for me :(